# Synonym of "less formal"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, british-english, compound-adjectives

As [casual conversation](https://www.talktocanada.com/blog/casual-conversation-in-esl-the-inside-scoop-part-iii#:%7E:text=Casual%20conversation%20means%20blabber%2C%20chatter,%E2%80%93%20Roget%27s%20Thesaurus%202014.) simply means an idle chatter, I wanted to know of a word which means a "formal talk". Not completely [formal](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/formal+talks#:%7E:text=(%20formals%20plural%20),necessarily%20a%20bit%20more%20formal.), but rather a word for a conversation where people talk only for a purpose; a word which would mean "[not casual, but less formal](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/55336)." [This](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/less_formal/synonyms) didn't help.

Think of a person(a loner) who doesn't like making friends but can talk with others only if the conversation holds some purpose.
What would be the word used to describe such a conversation?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a sentence in which the word could be used.

Comment: 'Serious' seems spot on, 'a serious conversation'  (which needn't be grave), but I think this is ELL-level. Also 'a meaningful conversation'. 'Non-trivial' is probably the wrong register. But reasonable research is needed (antonyms of 'trivial' etc).

Comment: @killingtime I wish I could include a meaningful sentence. Sorry if my explanation seems vague. The only situation I could think of was a lonely person who would indulge only in conversations that hold some purpose.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth I was considering "serious" before, but then again serious seems to hold a lot of weight. Meaningful is a great choice though! Thanks. Antonyms of trivial are really trivial.

Comment: Would you be willing to have a frank conversation with me? Don

Comment: @rhetorician I'm sorry sir but I couldn't grasp what you meant. Did you indicate "frank" as a possible answer? Or a simple conversation?

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth.  Except the expression 'casual conversation' does not necessarily mean 'casual' in the pejorative sense.  It can be serious.  I could have a casual conversation with a friend about Plato's Republic over coffee and a sandwich.  This is somewhere between 'serious' and 'frivolous'.  Or rather, a casual conversation can be on a serious topic, surely.

Comment: @amidst: "Frank" is a possible answer. "Let me be perfectly frank (or Ernest, if you prefer)" is something someone says when they want to have a semi-serious talk with you.(The "Earnest" part is a joke. Ernest means sincere, but it's also a person's name, as is Frank.) Even a normally shy person's ears would perk up, and they would willingly listen to what the person had to say.

Comment: @rhetorician True. "Let me be perfectly frank" surely has an alerting tone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say 'serious' or 'meaningful' are good, but how about 'purposeful' or 'genuine' or 'compelling' or 'thought-provoking'?

Comment: "Serious" seemed murky to me. "Meaningful" is a wise choice. Funny that "serious" and "meaningful" are synonyms. I considered "purposeful" before but I couldn't relate it to the situation I framed, but may work as an alternative. "Genuine", "compelling", "thought-provoking" - no.  I wish I could upvote for "meaningful".